# Python socket server lead to many unknow IPv6 appear in 'ss -a6' command output message

Tags: python, sockets, ipv6

I created several socket to listen on the same IPv6 but different ports.The code is here:

```
servers = []
HOST = '2408:8456:8820:3be3:2d36:cf80:959:a562'
PORTS = [65001,65002,65003,65004,65005,65006,65007,65008,65009]
for PORT in PORTS:
    ds = (HOST, PORT)
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server.bind(ds)
    server.listen(5)
    servers.append(server)


while True:
    # Wait for any of the listening servers to get a client
    # connection attempt
    readable, _, _ = select.select(servers, [], [])
    ready_server = readable[0]

    conn, addr = ready_server.accept()
    .....
```

After the code runs,I checked TCP connecting via 'ss -a6',the shows the following message:

```
Netid State  Recv-Q Send-Q      Local Address:Port      Peer Address:PortProcess

tcp   LISTEN     0      5        [2408:8456:8820:3be3:2d36:cf80:959:a562]:65009                                 [::]:*                                          
tcp   LISTEN     0      5         [2408:8456:8801:9b7c:39:f306:e024:840a]:65009                                 [::]:*                                          
tcp   LISTEN     0      5       [2408:8456:8801:9b7c:8c37:ea98:3d70:ae57]:65009                                 [::]:*                                          
tcp   LISTEN     0      5       [2408:8456:8801:3e57:b04f:caa0:1a8f:e434]:65009                                 [::]:*                                          
tcp   LISTEN     0      5       [2408:8456:8801:3e57:583f:4582:1d48:170a]:65009                                 [::]:*                                          
tcp   LISTEN     0      5       [2408:8456:8801:3e57:5811:9d23:7966:a465]:65009                                 [::]:*                                          
tcp   LISTEN     0      5       [2408:8456:8801:3e57:384b:b672:2fa9:c2b4]:65009                                 [::]:*                                          
tcp   LISTEN     0      5                                           [::1]:ipp                                   [::]:*                                          
tcp   LISTEN     0      4096                           [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:6942                                     *:*                                          
tcp   LISTEN     0      5        [2408:8456:8820:3be3:2d36:cf80:959:a562]:65001                                 [::]:*                                          
tcp   LISTEN     0      5         [2408:8456:8801:9b7c:39:f306:e024:840a]:65001
.............
```

I am confused about the 'Local Address:Port' column,most of them are not my IPv6,so where are they come from? Could any body help me.Thank you.

Comment: They might be something like IPv6 Privacy Extensions addresses which makes up random addresses on the same network for your computer, so that different websites see different addresses - harmless

Comment: Thanks for you help,I have read your answer and learn more form Google.